# Is there any difference between "careless" and "irresponsible"?

Tags: meaning, difference, synonyms

I know that they are synonyms. But is there any slight difference between them?

Comment: Please edit your question to include research you've done and your own understanding of the two words up to this point. (For example, have you contrasted their definitions using a dictionary? Compared sentences from books or online resources to see how they are used differently?)

Comment: I completely agree with @pyobum here. You got three answers in two hours, and, for the most part, these answers simply gave two definitions and said little else. This question makes ELL look like a dictionary concierge service. Please, research this on your own first, and then [share the results of that research](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439), so we can start the conversation from there.

Answer (score 1):

Careless and Irresponsible have lot of difference in meaning.

[Careless](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/careless) - Taking insufficient care.

> "It is natural for careless writers to run into faults they never
>   think of"

[Irresponsible](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irresponsible) - One who has no sense of responsibility.

> "behaved like an irresponsible idiot"

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think I got it now.
If you forget about you tasks you're probably careless. But if you don't care (don't want to care for/thinks it's not important) about your child properly than you're irresponsible. Are these examples correct?

Answer (score -1):

They are different terms:

Careless -

> Not giving sufficient attention or thought to avoiding harm or errors.

Irresponsible -

> A person not showing a proper sense of responsibility.

Comment: What dictionary did you get these definitions from? (You should cite quoted definitions.)

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3Acareless

Answer (score -2):

They are very different, cannot be used interchangeably at all.

Careless — Do not care.

Irresponsible — It is your responsibility to "care" but you did not.

Comment: Cannot be used interchangeably at all? I disagree; they may not be complete synonyms, but there is still quite a bit of overlap. Imagine me telling my 10-year-old son: _"You left your baseball glove out in the rain; that was very _______ of you."_ I'd say either word could fill in the blank, and the sentence meaning doesn't change very much.